# Why my game in pygame is so slow?

Tags: python

I am making a game in Pygame. Now I have only one rectangle is moving on screen. The direction of rectangle can be changed from keyboard.

main.py :

```
import pygame
import sys
import player
import room

# Colors
black = (0, 0, 0)
white = (255, 255, 255)
red = (255, 0, 0)
blue = (0, 255, 0)
green = (0, 0, 255)

# Global variables
S_WIDTH = 800
S_HEIGHT = 800
FPS = 60
# player speed
SPEED = 2

# Initialization 
pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode([S_WIDTH, S_HEIGHT])
pygame.display.set_caption("Py-Man Alpha")
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

# Game class
class Game(object):
"""
This is main class of game.
All game events will happen here.
"""
Player = player.Player(blue, 50, 50, 0, 0) 
def __init__(self, screen, running):
    self.screen = screen
    self.running = running

    self.run()

def run(self):
    while self.running:
        # Events
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            # If user hits 'x'
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                self.running = False
            # Keyborad events
            elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                    self.Player.direction = 'up'
                    self.Player.move(SPEED, WALLS)
                elif event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                    self.Player.direction = 'down'
                    self.Player.move(SPEED, WALLS)
                elif event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                    self.Player.direction = 'left'
                    self.Player.move(SPEED, WALLS)
                elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                    self.Player.direction = 'right'
                    self.Player.move(SPEED, WALLS)
                elif event.key == pygame.K_p:
                    self.Player.direction = 'pause'
        # Clear screen
        self.screen.fill(white)

        #Draw
        self.Player.move(SPEED, WALLS)
        self.Player.draw(self.screen)
        for wall in WALLS:
            wall.draw()

        # Set clock
        clock.tick(60)

        # Update screen
        pygame.display.flip()

    # End of game
    pygame.quit()
    sys.exit()

# Tests
game = Game(screen, True)
```

player.py:

```
#imports
import pygame

class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
"""
This class represent the player image
and has the player actions.
"""
direction = 'right'
def __init__(self, color, width, height, x, y):
    # Pygame constructor
    pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)

    # Init. variables
    self.color = color
    self.width = width
    self.height = height 

    # Create sprite
    self.image = pygame.Surface([width, height])
    self.image.fill(self.color)
    self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
    self.rect.x = x
    self.rect.y = y

def draw(self, screen):
    # Draw player on the screen
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, self.color, [self.rect.x, self.rect.y, self.width, self.height], 0)

def move(self, speed, walls):
    # Move the player
    if self.direction == 'up':
        self.rect.y -= speed
    elif self.direction == 'down':
        self.rect.y += speed
    elif self.direction == 'left':
        self.rect.x -= speed
    elif self.direction == 'right':  
        self.rect.x += speed
```

so, how I can speed up my game? How I can improve speed? Where I wrong?
Thanks!

EDIT:
The refresh of monitor is slow. I press 'up' key , but monitor take command after 2-3 seconds. Why?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about improving working code, it might be better suited for codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: Have you tried increasing the `SPEED` variable? I bet that would give you more speed.

Comment: what is slow? refreshing the screen or the speed of the player?

Comment: perhaps you can try to refresh only when an action is done?

Comment: I agree with @Tim. For this question to be off-topic, you need to profile your code and identify the bottleneck, then ask about it specifically.

Answer (score 0):

You can increase `SPEED` or `clock.tick(60)`

But I prefer to increase `SPEED`.

`clock.tick(60)` means `60 FPS` and you could increase it but many monitors refresh its screen with `60Hz` and it means `60 FPS`. Bigger FPS means more work for CPU so it is hotter and you can hear CPU fan :)

BTW: Human eye needs at least 24 FPS to see animation.